Fingers not moving rigify for rokoko
I'm trying to use rigify for rokoko mocap and have followed the tutorials on setting up the rig for this.(So without clicking 'Generate Rig') But no matter what adjustments I make to the bone direction the fingers will not move with the armature. When posed the finger bones just move the rest of the arm. I'm new to rigging so this might be an expasperatingly obvious solution but I'd appreciate if anyone has any advice.
This is the project file:


I think we'll need to see your Blend file to see what's going on. You can share it via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to copy the full link on that page. Then edit your question here and paste the full link into it.

Thanks so much, I'm just trying to get the file size down and will upload it then. Appreciate your help. :)

This wouldn't work because I had shapekeys and hair on the model before applying the rig.
To solve the problem I:

Copied the model three times.

Deleted all the shapekeys, drivers and separate hair empties from two of the models.

Followed this tutorial with those two  models to solve a problem parenting to automatic weights: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EuHkd61RhDs

Transferred the shape keys from the original model back to the newly rigged model.
- To do this select the mesh with shapekey you want to transfer
- select the shapekey in the dropdown list
- shift select the mesh you want to transfer it to
- click the 'arrow down' button in your shapekey list,
- select 'transfer Shapekey'.


It's slow but it works.

Finally, I reapplied the hair to the newly rigged model.

This was a bit of a long way to go about things but it solved the problem.
